# magento dev:urn-catalog:generate command fails to detect secret file

Tags: magento2, xml, cli, development, phpstorm

I'm running the following command "magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml
"  to use the functionality of Magento 2 to automatically resolve all my URN's so PhpStorm will stop giving me warnings and errors.

But i get this error:
File ".idea/misc.xml" cannot be opened Warning!fopen(.idea/misc.xml): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Although i do work with PhpStorm, and the folder and file:  .idea/misc.xml do exist.

Any suggestions..?
Thank you

Comment: are you using the magento2 plugin for PHPStorm?

Comment: no, i'm using another task runner, b5 its called if you check on Git.

Comment: I don't know b5, but I would say you can't compare this to the magento2 plugin https://github.com/magento/magento2-phpstorm-plugin

Comment: ok i'm checking it now and will try it, but i don't see how this will fix my issue.

Comment: the plugin can generate the urn map for you

Comment: Ok it worked! And thats the solution 'style' i was searching for. Thank you @Philipp Sander
Also it works if you manually set an external URN from the GUI of PhpStorm.

Answer (score 4):

Try to create the .idea folder before run the `bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml`

If running Linux, from magento root folder:
`mkdir .idea && bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml`

Comment: can't believe this was all i needed, after losing my mind and manually setting hundreds of XSDs